# The Ultimate Pest

Tags: creature-design, mythical-creatures

An evil god has set out to create the worst pest imaginable. By mixing the features of existing creatures, they have wrought a monster designed to inflict the most damage to human society as is possible. They have been careful, though, to ensure that it can survive and breed in nature, and that all its features will aid it, lest it devolve into a common vermin. In this vein, the pests do not use magic in any way. The creature is the size of a pigeon, and, as rats are easily driven away by mortal magic, it has a mind wholly unlike any rodent. They have been set down in the modern world, to wreck their havoc

What features would be given to such a creature, and so what would it look like?

Comment: If what I learned is school is still valid, homo sapiens has caused the most deaths among humans in the past millennia.

Comment: @L.Dutch But they are not pigeon-sized hybrids, and don't fit the criteria of the question

Comment: @IcthysKing: Imagine The Borrowers but with a mean streak and rat like reproductive capacity. They would be one hell of a pest!!

Comment: @L.Dutch Humans are actually #2 on the list. 
 You are more likely to be killed by a mosquito than a another human. 
 http://2016.igem.org/Team:ColumbiaU_NYC/Results

Comment: @Nosajimiki Will it still be the case if all accidental and preventable deaths (resulted from human actions) are included?

Comment: @Otkin Good point, that figure seems to just be homicides.  If you factor in things like automobile accidents, genocides, and acts of war it looks like just over 2 million people are killed by other people a year (as of this century).  That said, it would have only been in the past few decades that people kill more people than mosquitoes.  Historically speaking, the average number of human deaths caused by war and homicide seems to be about 1-2% whereas throughout most of human history, mosquitos have caused 25% of human deaths.

Comment: The Comment section is not for extended discussions

Comment: VTC. This is an off-topic [High Concept Question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868). You're asking us to invent a creature ***from scratch.*** That's not our job. That's your job. Our job is to help you overcome *specific problems* during the development process. Literally the only meaningful detail you've provided is that it's the size of a pigeon.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Defining a Pest

The level to which a species is a pest can generally be measured by 4 criteria:

- It is difficult to eradicate.
- It is hazardous to our health.
- It damages our property.
- It competes with us for resources.

So, the ultimate pest should at the very least be able to preform on par with the best pests in the world on all 4 of these criteria.

**1: Difficult to Eradicate**

The most difficult species in the world to eradicate are very small with high reproduction rates like cockroaches or mosquitoes.  So making your pest the size of a pigeon actually makes this difficult.  Animals this size can normally be eradicated with hunting, aggressive trapping, or just plain taking out enough of them with our cars and windmills while going about our daily business.

So, to maximize thier difficulty to eradicate, you need to make thier environment one that puts them in close proximity to humans without exposing them to be easily killed by humans.  The best solution for this is to make them some sort of toxin resistant burrowing animal. With burrowing, you could have thousands of pigeon sized animals living under your home and not even know it.  You can not hunt them, you can not get in the way of thier normal paths to place traps... basically, the only way to kill them is poison the ground enough for it to saturate every layer of soil that they may be living in... so even when you do wipe out a colony of them, you do so at the cost of making your own environment uninhabitably toxic; so, it's a loose-loose situation to try to wipe them out.

**2: Hazardous to our Health**

An animal this size would have a hard time getting close enough to humans to poison or spread diseases directly, but these pests may by thier nature help to cultivate any number of secondary pests that help spread infectious diseases much like how rats did not spread the bubonic plague, but they cultivated the fleas that did.

**3: Damages our Property**

Pests like termites can do a LOT of damage to our property by eating our homes, but they can also generally be prevented by treating our wood with chemicals that are toxic to them.  Instead of eating our property, these animals will destroy it purely through thier excessive tunneling.  By undermining our homes and roads, they will create sink holes and change landscape gradients.  So, if a enough of them move in under your home, it is just a matter of time before thier excessive tunneling collapses destroying your house and probably harming anyone in the house at the time further contributing to Point #2.

**4: Competes with us for Resources**

Unlike rabbits or insects which usually attack our agriculture from above, these guys attack our food supply from safely underground by tunneling under plants and eating thier roots.  So your seemingly healthy crop will one day just start to wither and die from root damage.  This can also re-enforce Points #2 and #3 if they eat all the roots of that big pine tree next to your house causing it to fall over on to your home, your car, or even you.  If you want to make them even more pesky than this, you could have them like to tunnel up through our concreate foundations  and into the bottoms of our pantries and refrigerators.  One day you have a pantry full of food, the next day you have a pantry full of shredded empty bags and boxes and a fist sized hole in the floor... not to mention a very well fed colony of pests which are now using the energy from all that food to further undermine your home.

#### Give it a high Metabolic rate

So, if you have not figured it out, yet, I am basically describing something similar to a mole or ground hog, but these animals are generally not a major threat to humans because they are actually very inactive animals for mammals.  They generally burrow just enough to have a safe place to go and relax away from the troubles of the world, but THESE moles have had thier metabolic rates cranked way up so that they can tunnel faster and deeper and reproduce more quickly.  So really, they are more like meerkats than moles.

Higher metabolisms could also make them tough enough to fight off certain predators like snakes which are normally responsible for keeping tunneling rodent populations in check.  That said, meerkats are normally kept in check by birds of prey in lue of snakes because they spend so much time on the surface.  These meerkat like animals can live nearly thier whole lives underground by feeding mostly off of plant roots instead of meat which makes them harder to keep in check by predators.

#### Adding Intelligence to the Mix

By now you already have a pretty nasty pest, but it can get much worse.  Intelligence is not normally a required aspect of a pest species, but since the OP mentions that "it has a mind wholly unlike any rodent", we can assume he means it is smart.  Making a burrowing rodent intelligent can cause it to become much more effective at all four Pest Criteria.

While a meerkat can sometime beat a snake, it still is not able to reliably kill off all of its predators.  An intelligent pest however can raise above it's natural predator's through the use of weapons.  Even if they are not great at making thier own weapons, they could sneak into our homes at night to steal our knives, rat traps, and poisons.  So these smart meerkats will be able arm themselves and booby trap thier tunnels to out right exterminate anything that would otherwise eat them.  In the wild, they will be like tiny cavemen participating in the circle of life, but once they come into contact with human civilization, they will start aquiring the tools they need to kill off every cat, snake, hawk, and owl that even tries to move into thier territory.  This will cause thier populations to grow wildly out of control like a subterranean Rat Utopia.

As they begin organizing to slaughter animals that threaten thier survival, any attempt by humans to remove a colony of these pests would be perceived as an act of war.  While a dumb pest might see its dead brother in a mouse trap and get scared, an intelligent pest will see that and begin plotting its revenge.  So now families that actually try to remove super pest colonies from thier property are likely to end up getting thier necks slit while they sleep.

Population booms that happen when they get thier hands on human stuff also means that thier subterranean colonies will need to become MUCH larger than they would be in nature to accommodate everyone.  This amplifies the risk of  tunnel collapses and sink holes way beyond what any real world tunneling rodent would put us at risk for.

The population boom also means much more competition for resources.  As they wipe out thier predators, thier focus will quickly shift from avoiding being eaten to needing enough to eat.  Urban environments have limited numbers of plants to feed on which will increase how often they need to break into human homes to steel our food.  Intelligence also means they they will not just randomly dig and sometimes find our food, it means that they will listen to us moving around during the day looking for the sounds of opening refrigerators and pantries, rustling chip bags, etc. and plan out exactly where and when to dig into our homes to safely make away with our food.

Comment: Make it a souped up naked mole rat colony and you’ve essentially got giant fleshy termites. Also they’re immune to cancer, pain, and cripplingly toxic atmospheric CO2 concentrations, so there’s that...

Comment: 5) killing it harms us.  example:  Facehugger's acid

Comment: @TonyEnnis  Killing it harms us alone does not make an animal a pest.  Killing off all of our cattle is harmful to humans, but that does not make cows a pest.  Things like facehugger acid is IMO more of a means to the end of achieving better difficulty to eradicate and hazardous to our health... so, it can certainly make a pest species nastier though.

Answer (score 4):

### Take the Raven, add the Vulture, then square it

Locusts are honestly the best example of calamitous, civilization-ending vermin. But since you're looking for a pigeon-size vermin, the next best thing without investing too much effort into modifications would be to take the common raven and the common vulture, merge them and just crank their already existing features to 11.

The common raven is one of the smartest birds out there, it's a particularly careful creature and rarely ever being caught off guard. It's also proven to be quite capable of learning both by example and experience, so it's the best candidate for adapting into a pigeon-sized pest.

The common vulture is also a particularly careful creature, with its main feature being its infectious nature. While they themselves are pretty resilient to diseases, they are most often the carriers and will spread them to their food.

Merge the two, crank all of their features to 11 except the reproduction rate which should be cracked up as high as it can possibly go and you have one hell of a pest to deal with. Intelligent and unpredictable makes them hard to track down and eradicate, patient and careful makes them difficult to notice, highly infectious of crops and anything they come in contact with makes them extremely unwanted by anyone other than themselves and, most importantly, their high reproduction rate means that nothing short of an apocalyptic slaughter would dent their numbers.

PS EDIT: If you're worried about the pest not being aggressive enough, that feature kicks into high gear once the population peeks and, the further it grows the worst it becomes.

Comment: (Did you mean "vulture"? I've never seen it spelled with a 'ch' before...)

Comment: ... sorry seems I had a brainfart there, will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

*Tribbles*

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tribble

Your pest needs to spread widely and cause disruptions. The easiest way to do that is to enlist the populace to do the spreading and to aid in the disruptions. Tribbles work great in that way. Make it so everyone feels compelled to cater to their tribbles' needs over anything else, and you're set.